# Safari doing premature GET?

Tags: safari, get

I have a PHP script running on a website which logs the number of times access is associated with a key:
http://www.mywebsite.com/admin-query.php?key=8469f8847b8b4d05364ae400d4071d93

If the URL is incomplete and I go to manually alter the URL in the top bar of Safari 13.0.5, when the URL matches what was previously entered, **before I even press return**, I notice that the script has been run and my access tally associated with that key in MySQL database has been incremented.

To be clear... altering the "admin-query" in the URL to "admin-query1" and then back again **without pressing return** causes the "Top Hit" and "Google Suggestions" popup to appear, at which point the PHP script is run.

**How can that be so?**

I've tested with Chrome 81.0.4044.122, and didn't see the same result.

Comment: Post the code you are using.

Comment: The code isn't the issue.  The fact that the PHP script is called at all on Safari (but not Chrome) is the issue.  In fact, a one-liner PHP script that echoes the current date-time will reveal Safari's folly.

Comment: So the PHP tag should be removed if it is not about PHP.